# En donde puedo encontrar informacion sobre este tipo de modelado, quisiera entender el proyecto que descargue

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera encontrar informacion sobre este tipo de modelado para aprender a desarrollarlo yo mismo.

Si necesitan mas informaciòn del proyecto yo la facilitaria, estoy aprendiendo.

Algunas preguntas especificas que tengo son:

1. Por que los controladores tienen la extencion .JS y no .Cs?
2. Por que no es posible acceder al nav var del proyecto principal para realizar modificaciones?
3. Como podria añadir nuevas funcionalidades al codigo?

Gracias por la atencion.

Cordial saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1- porque son archivos javascript 2- no veo ningún nav bar 3- si quieres modificarlo solo abre el archivo y empieza

Comment: Luis, te invito a pasar por nuestro [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para leer acerca de [qué tipo preguntas debes evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) y [sobre qué temas sí puedes preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Tambien te invito a leer [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Leyendo esos enlaces comprenderás por qué tal vez esta pregunta termine cerrada. No se adecúa al formato del sitio

Comment: Los archivos Javascript y demás que no suele haber en un programa normal de .NET están ahí porque son parte del desarrollo de aplicaciones web. Si te fijas, en los componentes que puedes instalar a Visual Studio lo menciona.